# Inverse Y axis in Python scatter plt

Tags: python, matplotlib

I need to invert Y axis in my plt scatter plot. I tried this:

```
x = [5, 10, 65, 28, 0]
y = [0, 6, 17, 22, 27]

scatter = plt.scatter(x, y, s=1, alpha=1).invert_yaxis() #here I need to invert


plt.show()
```

In other words, I want to have value 27 in the left down corner and 0 in the top left corder. How can I fix it please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use can use `ax.invert_yaxis`:

```
# create an axis instance with `subplots
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
scatter = ax.scatter(x, y, s=1, alpha=1) #here I need to invert
ax.invert_yaxis()   # here how you can invert

plt.show()
```

Output:

[image]